# FileoutputStream / bufferreader

Tags: android, fileoutputstream

I have an equation which result is displayed in a TextView. 
Then i have another TextView which act like a History. This History i want to save with a file and the file should be reloaded after the app will be killed an restarted.

Whats i dont understand is that the second TextView which is the View that i will save is displayed wierd stuff after starting the app

Thise line over and over again.

```
android.widget.TextView{41852c0 VFED.VCL ..... ID32,316-419,351 #7f09000a app:id/tvHistory}
```

My own Code:

```
final static String FILENAME = "marks.txt";
mNotenHistory=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tVhistory);
mNotenHistory.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());

private void loadTextfromFile()
    {
        File f = new File(getFilesDir(),FILENAME);
        try {
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(f));
            String line;
            try {
                while ((line = br.readLine()) != null)
                {
                    mNotenHistory.setText(line+"\n"+mNotenHistory.getText());
                }
                br.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

@Override
    public void onClick(View view)
    {
       [...]

           mNotenHistory.setText(mNotenHistory.getText() + "\n" + string_note);
           String noten_history_string = String.valueOf(mNotenHistory);
           try {
               FileOutputStream fo = openFileOutput(FILENAME, Context.MODE_APPEND);
               fo.write(noten_history_string.getBytes());
               fo.write("\n".getBytes());

           } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
               e.printStackTrace();
           } catch (IOException e) {
               e.printStackTrace();
           }


       }
```

Comment: Dont forget to close all streams after you use them , sometime they create memory leaks and make some garble output.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the offending line:

`String noten_history_string = String.valueOf(mNotenHistory);`

Look at this definition, from the Android documentation:

```
public static String valueOf(Object value)
```

> Added in API level 1
>
> Converts the specified object to its string representation. If the object is null return the string "null", otherwise use `toString()` to get the string representation.

The `TextView` class inherits `toString()` from the `View` class. Here is its definition:

> `public String toString ()`
>   Added in API level 1
>
> Returns a string containing a concise, human-readable description of this object. Subclasses are encouraged to override this method and provide an implementation that takes into account the object's type and data. The default implementation is equivalent to the following expression: `getClass().getName() + '@' + Integer.toHexString(hashCode())`

So this is your problem. `String.valueOf(mNotenHistory)` does **not** give you the text within the text view. Thus, you are writing something else (specifically, the line you mentioned) to your file. To obtain the text from your `TextView`, use the `getText()` method instead. This is what the line should look like:

```
String noten_history_string = mNotenHistory.getText();
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation but it is still not working. If i change these lines Android Studio throws an error "Incompatible Types Required:java.lang.String Found: java.lang.CharSequence. The Quick fix would be -> Cast to java.lang.String or Wrap using String.ValueOf and then it is working but not exactly like i want.

Comment: When you make the change, what is written to your text file?

Comment: If i write in the TextView a 6.0 \n 1.0 and it shows correctly in the TV. If i close/kill the app and watch the file manually with root explorer there is an \n  1.0 \n 1.0 \n 6.0. If i restart the app there is just a 6.0.

Comment: Problem solved -> i wrote the whole textview in the file and not just the single entry....

Comment: Very nice! I'd recommend writing a full answer so people don't have to search through the comments to find the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Quick resume what i do want to a complish.

TextView A gets the result of an equation which is clear after each new calculation.
To save the result there is TextView B.
The Results should write from botton to top in TextView B so that the newest in on top.
The same time it should write the content of the TextView into a file.

After closing/killing the App and reopen it the TextView B will show all the saved data.

A Reset Button should clear all the content of the file so it will be empty.